# Off the shelf or roll my own?

Tags: android, video-streaming, voip

I want to take an Android based tablet - *not* a phone, I need a large screen and I don't need 3G.

The guy with the tablet will attach a web cam to it and a s/w application in the Adnroid tablet will stream the cameras feed to a web page (there may later be a need to stream video back to the Android tablet - tbd).

Additionally, I need 2 way Voice over IP.

I may (tbd) need to use a TCP interace to a device which might, or might not, be achieved through the Andoid.

With so much open: is there any open source that can handle that, either as a grooup or individually, or should I code my own? Since I don't normally do this kinds of stuff what's the best approach, in terms of protocols, etc

I'd like to demo something in a month or so.  Sorry that this is vague - but so is the person asking for it (which might make me lean towards roll your won simply because of shifting requirements. But I might roll my own around off the shelf building block, for instance if I can find off the shelf open source VoiP, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any open source that can
>   handle that, either as a grooup or
>   individually, or should I code my own?

AFAIK, there is virtually no "open source that can handle that" **for Android**. In fact, you will need hardware modifications and drivers to support webcams, let alone anything else on your to-do list.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to reply. What hardware mods/drivers? Surely a straightforward USB interface to an off the shelf webcam will do?

Comment: @mawg: Only if you are rolling your own firmware and are willing to add all the code necessary to that firmware to support webcams. Android does not natively support webcams, any more than it natively supports mice, or scanners, or printers, or most other peripherals. Heck, finding an Android device that supports USB host mode is a challenge.

Comment: Argh!  but thanks (+1)   and advice? Good URLs, sourceforge projects, etc? I'd had to have to develop device drivers (hmm, web cam with its won IP Address? At least a tablet has an Ethernet i/f ... but that's just the transport mechanism - I still need to get the images that it is capturing)

Comment: Or ...   Android is just a layer on top of Linux and Linux supports USB webcams ... maybe I bypass Android? Or ditch it/ignore it entirely and just build my app on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of mobile streaming services. Maybe they can help you with one half of your problem:

- http://www.ustream.tv/
- http://www.qik.com/
- http://bambuser.com/

Comment: +1 Thanks, I might look into this, but to be honest it's not so difficult, so there is almost certain to be a FOSS Android solution and, if not, I will code my own. Using a pay service is not very likely.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the Webcam, you can use the integrated camera on the phone itself to capture and stream. And, yes, you 'll have to develop something on your own esp. with changing requirements.

Comment: yes, but I have to use a tablet, and I don't find any with camera. Besides, there camera needs to be separate from teh device (sorry that I didn't make that clear)  +1 for taking th etime to reply. Thanks

Comment: what size tablet are you looking for ? May be, I can help with one with integrated camera and android 1.5 running on it.